# Using the idea of Derivatives/Integrals prove existence of 'c'

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ is a differentiable function and $g(x)$ is a twice differentiable such that

$|f(x)|\le 1$

and $f'(x)=g(x)$.

Also if $(f(0))^2+(g(0))^2=9$

then prove that there exists some $c$ in the interval $(-3,3)$ such that $g(c)g''(c)< 0$

Comment: It means $(f(0))^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second Solution:
WLOG, $g(0)\in[2\sqrt2,3]$ and $g(c)>0$

Also, $\int_{0}^xg(t)dt=f(x)-f(0)$

$\left|\int_{0}^xg(t)dt\right|=\left|f(x)-f(0)\right|\leq\left|f(x)\right|+\left|f(0)\right|\leq1+1=2$

In neighbourhood of $x=0$,$g(x)$ will assume the value which is atleast $\alpha$.

Let this value of $\alpha$ be $2$.

$g(x)$ cannot take the value greater than or equal to $2$ all the time because if this happens,then

$\int_{0}^3g(t)dt\geq\int_{0}^32dt$,i.e.$\int_{0}^3g(t)dt\geq6$,

which is a contradiction.

Let $a\in(0,3)$,where $g(a)=2$ and similarly let $b\in(-3,0)$,where $g(b)=2$.

By Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem(LMVT),we have

$g'(p)=\frac{g(a)-g(0)}{a-0}$ and $g'(q)=\frac{g(0)-g(b)}{0-b}$,where $p\in(0,a)$ and $q\in(b,0)$.

One can observe that $g'(p)<0$ and $g'(q)>0$.

Since $g(x)$ is twice differentiable,we have once again by LMVT

$g''(c)=\frac{g'(p)-g'(q)}{p-q}$

Clearly,$g''(c)<0$.

Thus $g(c)g''(c)<0$ for some $c\in(-3,3)$

Answer (score 1):

I would want to get the solution improvised or can someone come up with a better explanation.

Let us assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $g(x) > 0$ and $g''(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (-3,3).$

Note that the second condition implies that $g(x)$ is a convex (concave-up) function;

hence, by Jensen's inequality, we have $g(\frac{a+b}{2}) < \frac{g(a)+g(b)}{2}$ for all $a,b \in (-3,3).$

In particular, for $a=x$ and $b=-x,$ we have $2 \cdot g(0) < g(x)+g(-x)$ for all $x \in (-3,3)$ ... $(*)$

Now, $f'(x) = g(x)$

$\Rightarrow \int_{-3}^{3}f'(x) \, dx = \int_{-3}^{3}g(x) \, dx$

$\Rightarrow f(3)-f(-3) = \int_{0}^{3}(g(x)+g(-x)) \, dx$

... [using the identity $\int_{-a}^{a}g(x) \, dx= \int_{0}^{a}(g(x)+g(-x)) \, dx$]

$\Rightarrow f(3)-f(-3) > 2 \int_{0}^{3}g(0) \, dx$ ... [using $(*)$]

$\Rightarrow f(3)-f(-3) > 6 \cdot g(0)$

$\Rightarrow 6 \cdot g(0) < |f(3)-f(-3)| \le |f(3)|+f(-3)| \le 1+1 = 2$

$\Rightarrow 0 < g(0) \le \frac13 .$

But the above condition combined with the fact that $|f(x)| \le 1$ implies that $f(0)^{2}+g(0)^{2}\le 1+\frac{1}{3^{2}}= \frac{10}{9},$ which contradicts the condition that $f(0)^{2}+g(0)^{2}= 9.$

Therefore our assumption is clearly wrong and thus $g(x)$ and $g''(x)$ cannot be of same sign.

[b]Case 2[/b]: If we assume that $g(x) < 0$ and $g''(x) < 0$ for all $x \in (-3,3),$ we arrive at a contradiction in a similar way as shown above.

Thus, $g(x)$ and $g''(x)$ cannot be both positive or both negative for $x \in (-3,3).$ This implies that $g(c) \cdot g''(c) \le 0$ for some $c \in (-3,3).$ And, we are done.